# How to decrypt a property value when using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties, jasypt

I have a properties file containing values like `jdbc.password={enc}laksksjdjdj`

Using JDK 1.7 and Spring 4.1.5 my configuration class looks like this

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:env.properties")
})
@ComponentScan("com.acme")
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;    

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        return new EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to translate *any* values in my properties file from an encrypted value to the actual value. Some values will be encrypted and some won't. This is what I have attempted so far and when I place a breakpoint on `convertProperties()` the `props` argument is always empty. I can't make any sense of this because I can see that at this point `this.environment` is loaded with all the properties from the files.

```
public class EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
{
    @Override 
    protected void convertProperties(Properties props)
    {
        Enumeration<?> propertyNames = props.propertyNames();

        while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {

            String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.nextElement(); 
            String propertyValue = props.getProperty(propertyName); 

            // String convertedValue = <translate the value>;

            props.setProperty(propertyName, convertedValue);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties mergeProperties() throws IOException {
        final Properties mergedProperties = super.mergeProperties();
        convertProperties(mergedProperties);
        return mergedProperties;
    }
}
```

Has anyone been able to achieve this using `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`? I have similar logic working in older applications using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` but wanted to use the newer Spring configuration.

I noticed that Jasypt has a similar `EncryptablePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` but this behaves in the same fashion, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason using the `@PropertySources` annotation(s) does not work as expected.

When `EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.convertProperties()` is called the autowired `ConfigurableEnvironment` does not contain the entries from my properties files. There are no references to my listed properties files at all.

To get around this limitation I removed the annotations and explicitly loaded these resources in in the config class. So it now reads like this

```
@ComponentScan("com.acme")
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig
{ 
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer p = new EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(new KeyfileDecryptor());
        p.setLocations(
                new ClassPathResource("application.properties"),
                new ClassPathResource("env.properties")
                );
        return p;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(
            @Value("${jdbc.driverclassname}") String driverclassname,
            @Value("${jdbc.url}") String url,
            @Value("${jdbc.username}") String username,
            @Value("${jdbc.password}") String password)
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverclassname);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

This change introduced the issue that the autowired `ConfigurableEnvironment` will be `null` so I had to change to using `@Value` injection in order to configure my `dataSource` from the properties.

Everything now works as expected and `EncryptedPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.convertProperties()` receives all of the properties values from both files.

Answer (score -1):

Written one sample application to do add support for using Encrypted values here

https://github.com/pushpendra-jain/spring-examples/tree/master/PropertySourcesPlaceholderEncrypter

Basically instead of trying to invoke its convertProperty method overrided its processProperties method and getting the job done and code surely does not change any existing behavior.

see https://github.com/pushpendra-jain/spring-examples/blob/master/README.md for steps.